# Allow access to url with htaccess

Tags: htaccess

I block my entire development site and just provide exclusions for certain IPs. Such as:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}        !123\.34\.12\.123
```

My IP changes all the time and I have DynDNS so I thought I might be able to use something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^somename\.dyndns\.org
```

That doesn't work. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, dyndns domains won't work, since Apache uses reverse lookup to find the domain. If you are using a domain of your own, your PTR records must be correct.